# export table with expdp oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, expdp

I am trying to export a table from my oracle database with SID=DB034 with username=b034. I am using this command:

```
expdp b034/aDmin123456789@DBB034 tables=B034.BIL_CUSTOMER_GROUP, DEPT directory=exp_test dumpfile=dump_test.dmp logfile=log_test.log
```

My directory is correct and also I had granted privileges to b034 user. After running the command I get this error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you discover when you googled 'ORA-12154' ?

Comment: @EdStevens said that there may be a difference between the IP address of the database and the IP that expdp wants to connect.

Comment: I don't know what you found that said that an ORA-12154 has anything to do with IP addresses.  It doesn't.  It means _only_ that your connect string (DBB034, in your case) could not be found in the tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause of `ORA-12154` is that database alias (`DBB034`) can't be found in `TNSNAMES.ORA` file (the one `expdp` is using. If you have more than a single Oracle product installed on your computer, I suggest you use `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable. Say if you need instructions).

That's something like *old-fashioned* telephones - you're trying to call someone, but can't find their name in any phone book.

So, what to do? Add `DBB034` into `TNSNAMES.ORA`.

---

As you asked (in a comment) how `TNSNAMES.ORA` alias looks like, here you are:

```
DBB034=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=11.222.33.44)        --> put host name or its IP address here
      (PORT=1521)                --> usually 1521, but doesn't have to be
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=dbb034)      --> lucky guess; maybe it is called differently
    )
  )
```

Basically, if you aren't sure what to put in there, ask your DBA, they know.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you give me more detail on how to do this? or any links that can help?

Comment: I posted an example; have a look.